# How to filter across multiple dataframes in R?

Tags: r

I have 5 `data.frame`s, with the same columns.

I want to filter the same condition through a function and iterate through all the `data.frame`s.

I created this function:

`filtrar <- function(x){y<<- filter(x, e27 >= 14)}`

But I cannot apply it to all my `data.frame`s at the same time, I tried this and didn't work:

`filenames <- list.files()`

`for (i in filenames){filtrar(i)}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a list of file paths from where you want to read the data. Assuming you want to read data from csv files in your working directory you could do :

```
filenames <- list.files(pattern = '\\.csv$', full.names = TRUE)
```

1. If you want final output to be list of dataframes you can use :

```
lapply(filenames, function(x) {
  data <- subset(read.csv(x), e27 >= 14)
  return(data)
}) -> list_data
```

2. If you want the filtered dataframes as separate dataframe in global environment do :

```
names(list_data) <- paste0('df', seq_along(list_data))
list2env(list_data, .GlobalEnv)
```

This will create dataframes named `df1`, `df2` etc in your global environment.

3. If you want to write them back as csv do :

```
lapply(names(list_data), function(x) 
       write.csv(list_data[[x]], paste0(x, '.csv'), row.names = FALSE))
```

This will write files named `df1.csv`, `df2.csv` in your working directory.

Comment: I see your point. But its possible to apply directly the function i created in (2)?

Comment: No. That will create a new object `y` in your global environment and will update it everytime you run the function with `lapply`.